# Can I use map tag in as build pager in bxslider ? I want to use map tag for my pagination

Tags: html, css

Please help me. Thanks.
Here is my html code:

```
 <img id="method_pagination" src="http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/9201309060150066_approach-retina-slider-clear2.png" usemap="#method_pagination" border="0" width="832" height="250" alt="" />
                <map id="_method_pagination" name="method_pagination">
                <area shape="poly" coords="0,9,113,40,114,201,0,232," href="#" alt="explore" title="explore"  class="explore" data-slide-index="0"/>
                </map>
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <strong>Simplify</strong>
                        <p>
                            <!--content-->
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('.slides').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#_method_pagination'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the JS-Code.

Open the bxslider.js and search for this line:

```
slider.pagerEl.delegate('a', 'click', clickPagerBind);
```

and change it to this:

```
slider.pagerEl.delegate('area', 'click', clickPagerBind);
```